# $P:E\to B$ & $f$ loop If there is a lifting $\hat{f}:I\rightarrow E$ of $f$ with $\widehat{f(0)}\neq\widehat{f(1)}$ then $f$ is not null-homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $P:E\rightarrow B$ be a covering and $f:I\rightarrow B$ be a loop. If there exists a lifting $\hat{f}:I\rightarrow E$ of $f$ with $\widehat{f(0)} \neq \widehat{f(1)}$ then $f$ is not null-homotopic.

Q1-Here null homotopic means the singleton right?

Q2- I know that $f\circ p=\hat{f}$. How do we use this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Null-homotopic means being homotopic to a constant map. In other words, $f:I\to B$ is nullhomotopic if there exists a map $H:I\times I \to B$ such that $H(t,0)=f(t)$ and $H(t,1)=b_0$ for some point $b_0\in B$.

Q2. This equality doesn't really make sense. The codomain of $p$ is not the same as the domain of $f$. The equality you are looking for is $f=p\circ \hat{f}$.

As for the statement you are trying to prove, i assume you mean that $f$ is not null-homotopic relative to the boundary (or not null-homotopic as a loop $f:S^1\to B$). The statement as written is not true. Any map $I\to X$ is nulhomotopic since $I$ is contractible. However, this rephrased statement is true. Let us prove it.

We will prove it by showing the contrapositive statement. Assume that $f:I\to B$ is null-homotopic relative to $\partial I$. Then there exists a map $H:I\times I \to B$ such that $H(t,0)=f(t)$, $H(t,1)=b_0$, and $H(0,s)=H(1,s)=b_0$ where $b_0:=f(0)$. Let $\hat{f}:I\to E$ be any lift i.e. $f=p\circ \hat{f}$. Now we use the lifting properties of covering spaces. The homotopy lifts to a homotopy $\hat{H}:I\times I \to E$ such that $H(t,0)=\hat{f}(t)$. Being a lift here means that $H=p\circ \hat{H}$. Let $e_0=\hat{f}(0)$. We see that $e_0=\hat{H}(0,0)$. Now we apply the unique lifting property. See e.g. Hatcher's book Proposition 1.34. This gives that the lifting of the constant path $H|_{\{0\}\times I}$ is the constant path at $e_0$. Hence $\hat{H}|_{\{0\}\times I}$ is constantly $e_0$. Similarly, we now see that $\hat{H}|_{I\times \{1\}}$ is constantly $e_0$, and then that $\hat{H}|_{\{1\}\times I}$ is constant $e_0$. In particular $\hat{H}(1,0)=e_0$. We then see that $\hat{f}(0)=e_0=\hat{H}(1,0)=\hat{f}(1)$.
This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'the singleton'. The term 'null-homotopic' means the loop is homotopic to the constant map $f(t)=x_0\quad \forall t\in I$. Maybe you mean that the image of $f$ consists of the singleton $\{x_0\}$, which is true if $f$ is null-homotopic.

For your second question, I believe you have your compositions mixed up. Note that the domain of $f\circ p$ is $E$, while the domain of $\hat{f}$ is $I$, so they cannot be equal. Instead, you have the following: for a covering $p:E\to B$, a lift of $f:I\to B$ with respect to $p$ is a map $\hat{f}:I\to E$ such that $p\circ\hat{f}=f$. Intuitively, if you take the lifted path $\hat{f}$ in $E$, and push it down to $B$ via your covering, you should get your original path $f$ back.

Perhaps with this corrected version of your lifting statement, you can see whether the result in the question title is true.